# Secure way to access DB on Raspberry pi outside home network

Tags: postgresql, security, networking, raspberry-pi

I have a postgres database installed on my raspberry pi that works fine locally within my home network.  I would like to be able to access this from outside my home network.  I've done some research and from what ive seen port forwarding on my router or using a service like localtunnel or ngrok seem like viable solutions.

However, my question is if these open up any security risks on my home network?  If not, then great i can move forward with setting this up (i was leaning towards port forwarding on my router). But if there are concerns, what exactly are they and what steps can I take to have a secure setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose your database to the world with a weak password for a database superuser, that will definitely lower your security in a substantial way.  Hackers routinely patrol for such weak settings and exploit them, mostly for cryptocurrency mining but also to add you to botnets.  In those cases they don't care about your database itself, it is just a way in to get at your CPU/network connection.  They might also probe for valuable information appearing in your database, in which case they don't even need to be a superuser.

If you always run the latest bugfix version and use a strong password (like the output of `pwgen 20 -sy -1`) and use SSL or if you correctly use some other method of authentication and encryption, then it will lower security by only a minimal amount.

If you personally control every password, and ensure they are strong, and test that they are configured correctly to be required for log on (e.g. intentionally enter it wrong once to make sure you get rejected), I wouldn't worry too much the port forwarding providing bad guys access to the machine.  If you care about people being able to eavesdrop on the data being sent back and forth, then you also need SSL.

Encrypted tunnels of course are another solution which I am not addressing.

Comment: Thanks much for this info.  So port forwarding for access to a DB wont allow someone else to access the rest of the network?  Is the worst case access to the DB if the password was compromised?

Comment: It is always possible for there to an undiscovered bug in PostgreSQL itself, or maybe a bug in your router which is only usable when port forwarding is turned on. I can't rule those things out, but they are probably not your top concerns.  If the password compromised is for a database superuser, they have have access the machine as whichever OS user is running the PostgreSQL server (and whatever they can leverage that into), not just to the database itself.  If it is not a superuser account, then barring bugs or misconfiguration they only have access to the DB, not to the underlying machine.